How to match specific files with a shell pattern in unit test discoverer?
I want to run a suite of unit tests. The basic code is:
suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover('tests')

The documentation for the function mentions the pattern argument, which defaults to test_*.py:

Only test files that match the pattern will be loaded. (Using shell style pattern matching.)

I want only some of these tests to run, for example test_abcd, test_ab1, and test_ab3, but not test_ab2 (because it imports a file that may not be present). In a shell, I could match these files with:
test_{abcd,ab1,ab3}

But it fails inside the test discoverer. I also tried these patterns, but none of them work inside the discoverer:
test_\(abcd|ab1|ab3\)
test_abcd,test_ab1,test_ab3

One pattern that works inside the discoverer is test_ab[2-4], but it will also catch test_ab3, which I don't want.
How can I match these specific files with a shell pattern or the unit test discoverer?

If it's using regex test_ab(cd|[13]) is supposed to match, but if your function does not like parentheses and prefers brackets only, you can try e.g. test_abcd|test_ab[13]

@bobblebubble I tried both of these inside the Python unittest syntax and both fail to find the files.

is this question related? If so, you might try to escape the pipe with a backslash \| which would be weird indeed! Maybe also the parentheses like you did already.

Right, it is about the wildcard support in .discover that uses shell-style wildcards, not regex. Tags adjusted.

@emonigma I see! How about putting an answer yourself, I can't explain that well.

A pattern that should work is
test_ab[c12]*

depending on what else you want to match or not match.
For more detailed matching, How does Python's unittest library match patterns passed via the -p parameter? explains the process of matching with the fnmatch module. The capabilities are:
Patterns are Unix shell style:
*       matches everything
?       matches any single character
[seq]   matches any character in seq
[!seq]  matches any char not in seq

If you want more fine-grained control over which tests to run than pattern-matching allows, consider using loadTestsFromNames instead.

Thanks! I asked a follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79102009/how-to-load-tests-from-some-files-and-not-others

Lose the backslashes and it all matches as you wish.


Yes, it matches in a regular expression. I tested it inside the Python unittest function and it fails to find the files. Shall I produce an MRE?

Documentation says .discover uses shell-style wildcards, not regex.  So why did you tag this request with the  tag when it's not a feature of the software?

Also, did you look at the -k option (or the testNamePatterns attribute of testLoader)?  Something like -k abcd -k ab1 -k ab3...

@ChrisMaurer Why did you answer the question based on the keyword alone, when the title and question makes it clear that a shell pattern is needed?
