How to load tests from some files and not others?
I want to run a suite of unit tests in the tests folder. The basic code is:
suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover('tests')

I want only some of these tests to run, for example test_e1 if file e1.py is present, test_e5 if e5.py is present, but not test_e2 and test_e11 (because files e2.py and e11.py are missing).
I tried the pattern argument of the discoverer() function, which defaults to test_*.py, but it does not allow enough control for what I need (see How to match specific files with a shell pattern in unit test discoverer? ).
One answer in that thread suggests finding these tests with unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromNames, so I tried this code:
    file_list = []

    for some_file in some_file_list:
        full_filepath = os.path.join(some_dir, some_file)
        if not os.path.exists(full_filepath):
            continue
        file_list.append("tests/test_%s.TestDocs" % some_file)

    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromNames(file_list)
    print(suite)

The name TestDocs is the class name that inherits from the unit test:
class TestDocs(unittest.TestCase):

But this shows a list of failed tests such as:
<unittest.suite.TestSuite tests=[<unittest.loader._FailedTest testMethod=tests/test_>]>

How can I run tests only for a certain set of files?

'tests/test_foo.TestDocs' is a hybrid of a file path and a qualified module name. Assuming tests is a directory where Python will look for modules to import, you just want 'test_foo.TestDocs' as the test case class to load.

I tried that, removing tests/ from the string, and I still cannot find the tests. I believe the problem is the file containing this code, run_tests.py, is in one folder and the Python files with actual tests are in a subfolder, called tests. For now, I fixed it with a combination of loadTestsFromModule(), exec() to import the module, and eval() to add the module's tests to the suite, but I'm sure there is a cleaner way.

That's because you still need to ensure that tests is on sys.path, so that when the test framework tries to import test_foo, it knows where to look to find it.

Yes, it works now! Could you please write an answer? Also, isn't adding to sys.path against best practice, and should I have a better structure for my test files?

There are two ways to alter sys.path: directly from inside your code (which is the bad practice) or externally by using the PYTHONPATH environment variable. Better yet, install your code somewhere (like a virtual environment) that is already on the search path.

You are passing hybrid file-path/object names to loadTestsFromNames. Drop the tests from the name, and ensure that tests appears on your module search path, either by

Modifying sys.path before calling the method, or
Adding tests to the PYTHONPATH environment variable before running your tests.


The filesystem structure used to reproduce your code
I have created on my system the following structure:
test_project
  |- tests
  |    |- __init__.py
  |    |- test_e1.py
  |    |- test_e2.py
  |- production
  |    |- e1.py
  |- run_tests.py

In the folder tests there are:

test files test_e1.py, test_e2.py
the __init__.py file (tests must be a package for correct execution)

The folder production contains the file e1.py but not the file e2.py so tests method of the file test_e2.py must not be executed.
The file run_tests.py with changes
I have saved your code (changing one instruction and adding the instruction to execute the tests) in the file run_tests.py:
import unittest
import os

some_dir = "/path/to/production"
some_file_list = ["e1.py", "e2.py"]

file_list = []

for some_file in some_file_list:
    full_filepath = os.path.join(some_dir, some_file)
    if not os.path.exists(full_filepath):
        continue
    # file_list.append("tests/test_%s.TestDocs" % some_file)
    file_list.append("tests.test_%s.TestDocs" % some_file.split('.')[0])

suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromNames(file_list)
#print(suite)
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=3)
result = runner.run(suite)

With the previous filesystem structure your instruction:
file_list.append("tests/test_%s.TestDocs" % some_file)

becomes:
file_list.append("tests.test_%s.TestDocs" % some_file.split('.')[0])

Differences:

from the name of the file e1.py I have removed the extension by the split() instruction
I have used the dotted form "tests.test_%s.TestDocs" % some_file instead your "tests/test_%s.TestDocs" % some_file (see here for documentation of the method loadTestsFromName() and loadTestsFromNames()).

The output of the execution of the test suite
The content of test_e1.py is:
import unittest
from production import e1

class TestDocs(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_01(self):
        e1.func1_of_e1()

    def test_02(self):
        e1.func2_of_e1()


The content of production/e1.py is:
def func1_of_e1():
    print("func1_of_e1()")
    
def func2_of_e1():
    print("func2_of_e1()")

So the output execution is:
test_01 (tests.test_e1.TestDocs) ... ok
test_02 (tests.test_e1.TestDocs) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
func1_of_e1()
func2_of_e1()

So are executed the 2 tests (test_01 and test_02) contained in test_e1.py while tests contained in the file test_e2.py (not showed above) are not executed because e2.py is not present in the folder production.
